# WSWS5055E: Cannot find a Service for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/

Tags: java, oracle11g

Error occurred after calling from weblogic server

```
WSWS5055E: Cannot find a Service for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping webservices.jar (`WAS jar`) in the class path. For me it is working fine.